# Disabling a checkbox in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, checkbox, razor

I'm trying to disable a checkbox, but I'm getting an error and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. My code is this

```
@Html.CheckBox("", ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue, new { @disabled = true } )
```

which as far as I can tell, judging by other explanations of how to disable a checkbox, should work. However, I'm getting this error:

> CS1928: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' does not contain a
>   definition for 'CheckBox' and the best extension method overload
>   'System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.CheckBox(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,
>   string, bool, object)' has some invalid arguments

Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The CheckBox helper expects a boolean value as second parameter. Try like this:

```
@Html.CheckBox(
    "", 
    bool.Parse((string)ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue), 
    new { disabled = "disabled" } 
)
```

or if this is a strongly typed editor template to `boolean`:

```
@model bool
@Html.CheckBox("", Model, new { disabled = "disabled" })
```

Comment: Ahh, thank you. I understand what was happening now.

Parsing the FormattedModelValue as a bool didn't work, because it was already a bool, but casting it as (bool)ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue did. Thanks again for the help